# Call properties in Groovy-Script with JavaCode using SoapUI

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I've started to build a service monitor using SoapUI 5 (non-Pro edition). The service monitor should be able to:

1. Teststep1 (http Request): Call an URL, which genereates a token
2. Teststep2 (groovy script): Parse the response and save the token as a property
3. Teststep3 (http Request): Call another URL
4. Teststep4 (groovy script): Parse the repsonseHttpHeader, save the statusHeader in a testCase-property and check if it is '200', '400', '403'...
5. Teststep5 (groovy script): Write an email whenever it is not '200'

Steps 1 to 4 are working without any problems and also sending emails (step 5) by executing my script is working, but I would like to change the email content depending and the statusHeader.  For example:

- `404`: `The requested resource could not be found`
- `403` : `It is forbidden. Please check the token generator`
- ...

Code for parsing and saving httpHeaderStatusCode:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )

// get responseHeaders of ServiceTestRequest
def httpResponseHeaders = context.testCase.testSteps["FeatureServiceTestRequest"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders
// get httpResonseHeader and status-value
def httpStatus = httpResponseHeaders["#status#"]
// extract value
def httpStatusCode = (httpStatus =~ "[1-5]\\d\\d")[0]
// log httpStatusCode
log.info("HTTP status code: " + httpStatusCode)
// Save logged token-key to next test step or gloabally to testcase
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("httpStatusCode", httpStatusCode)
```

Code for sending email:

```
// From http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "yourUsername@gmail.com";
        final String password = "yourPassword";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yourSendFromAddress@domain.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("yourRecipientsAddress@domain.com"));
            message.setSubject("Status alert");
            message.setText("Hey there,"
                + "\n\n There is something wrong with the service. The httpStatus from the last call was: ");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do: I want to access the testCase `httpStatusCode` property saved on my first groovy script (last line) in my last groovy script where I send my email. Is there something, which can handle this?

I've searched for two hours, but I have't found something useful. A possible workaround would be that I have to call different Email-Scripts with different messages using if statements and the `testRunner.runTestStepByName` method, but changing the content of the email would be nicer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your class definition in the last groovy script, instead of `main` define a method to send the email which has `statusCode` as parameter in your `sendMailTLS` class. Then in the same groovy script where you define your class use `def statusCode = context.expand('${#TestCase#httpStatusCode}');` to get your property value and then create an instance of your class and invoke your method passing the property `statusCode` with:

```
// create new instance of your class
def mailSender = new SendMailTLS();
// send the mail passing the status code
mailSender.sendMail(statusCode);
```

All together in your groovy script have to look like:

```
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

// define the class
class SendMailTLS {

    // define a method which recive your status code
    // instead of define main method
    public void sendMail(String statusCode) {

        final String username = "yourUsername@gmail.com";
        final String password = "yourPassword";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yourSendFromAddress@domain.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("yourRecipientsAddress@domain.com"));


            message.setSubject("Status alert");

            // THERE YOU CAN USE STATUSCODE FOR EXAMPLE...
            if(statusCode.equals("403")){
                message.setText("Hey there,"
                + "\n\n You recive an 403...");
            }else{
                message.setText("Hey there,"
                + "\n\n There is something wrong with the service. The httpStatus from the last call was: ");
            }           

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

// get status code
def statusCode = context.expand('${#TestCase#httpStatusCode}');
// create new instance of your class
def mailSender = new SendMailTLS();
// send the mail passing the status code
mailSender.sendMail(statusCode);
```

I test this code and it works correctly `:)`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. For me it was not clear how to call the java class and how to create a instance of this with the statusCode parameter. Thank you so much and have a nice weekend! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

1. Add a map in your java class which contains all the expected
   Response codes, and Response Messages as you wanted to have either
   subject or content of email.
2. I would suggest you to have it in a method other than main so that
   you intiantiate class object and call method from soapui's groovy
   script, of course you do it with main as well.
3. Method should take response code as argument.
4. Use it as key to get the relevant value from the map and put it to
   email.
5. Create a jar file for your class and put jar file under
   $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory
6. In your soapui test case, for test step5 (groovy) call your method
   from the class you wrote like how you call in java. For example: How
   to call your java from soapui groovy given below

```
//use package, and imports also if associated
SendMailTLS mail = new SendMailTLS()
//assuming that you move the code from main method to sendEmail method 
mail.sendEmail(context.expand('${#TestCase#httpStatusCode}')
```